# python mechanize form login give TypeError

Tags: python, forms, mechanize, typeerror

I am using mechanize in python to log in a webpage.

Python code:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("https://example.com/page1/")
formcount =0 
for form in br.forms():
    if form.attrs['class'] == 'standardForm':
        br.select_form(nr=formcount)
        break
    formcount = formcount+1
print form
br.form['username_or_email']='username'
br.form['password']='password'
```

Then got TypeError for the line "br.form['username_or_email']='username'" as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    br.form['username_or_email']='username'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

From the line "print form", we can see some form info as below,

```
<POST https://www.example.com/login/?next=https%3A//example.com/page1/ application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <IgnoreControl(<None>=<None>)>
  <IgnoreControl(<None>=<None>)>
  <IgnoreControl(<None>=<None>)>
  <TextControl(username_or_email=)>
  <PasswordControl(password=)>
  <SubmitButtonControl(<None>=) (readonly)>>
```

May I know how can I provide right value to the form?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: @boardrider, thanks for your suggestion,  but I already post all the necessary info that I think is needed. The rest is sensitive data I can not provide to test, sorry for that

Comment: The idea of [mcve] is to show a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. No need to show any sensitive data in it.

Answer (score 0):

try the below.

```
br = mechanize.Browser()

br.open("https://example.com/page1/")
br.select_form("enter the login form name here")
br["enter user name field here"] = 'username'
br["enter password field name here"] = 'password'
br.submit()
```

I believe that the login form is not being assigned to the br object as you are missing the *select_form* function

Comment: thanks, you point one important thing, as there is no name and id for the form, I can only use the "class" to select it. I improved my script to use select_form, but still get the same error. I think you are correct, the form is not selected correctly.